# Verify an element exists in an array

Tags: ruby

I want to verify if an element exists in an array.

Here is my code :

I create a function to verify the existence of the value entered by the user :

```
def verify(list,valueUser,stepN)
    unless list.include?(valueUser)
        puts "It is not a valid Geek Type !"
        puts "Type the code of your Geek type (ex : GB for Geek of Business) : " 
        valueUser = gets
    else
        puts stepN
    end
end
```

I create my array :

```
geekTypes = [ "GB", "GL", "GC", "GMC", "GCA", "GM", "GCM", "GMD", "GCS", "GMU", "GCC", "GPA", "GE", "GP", "GED", "GS", "GFA", "GSS", "GG", "GTW", "GH", "GO", "GIT", "GU", "GJ", "G!", "GLS", "GAT"]
```

Then I call my function :

```
puts "Type the code of your Geek type (ex : GB for Geek of Business) : " 
geekTypeUser = gets

verify(geekTypes,geekTypeUser,stepTwo)
```

The problem is even I type a false value (which is not in the array), the program continue to the next step.

How can I fix my problem ?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: You sure it's not after the second input?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do - the problem is that there is no loop in your code. No matter whether the input is valid or false, the method exits before checking another input.

You should use [`while` or `until`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm) instead of the `unless`:

```
def verify(list,valueUser,stepN)
  until list.include?(valueUser)
    puts "It is not a valid Geek Type !"
    puts "Type the code of your Geek type (ex : GB for Geek of Business) : " 
    valueUser = gets.chomp
  end
  puts stepN
  valueUser
end 

geekTypes = [ "GB", "GL", "GC", "GMC", "GCA", "GM", "GCM", "GMD", "GCS", "GMU", "GCC", "GPA", "GE", "GP", "GED", "GS", "GFA", "GSS", "GG", "GTW", "GH", "GO", "GIT", "GU", "GJ", "G!", "GLS", "GAT"]
puts "Type the code of your Geek type (ex : GB for Geek of Business) : " 
geekTypeUser = gets.chomp

geekTypeUser = verify(geekTypes,geekTypeUser,stepTwo)
```

Notice that I added [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) after the `gets`, otherwise, your code would receive input ending with new lines (`"GB\n"` instead of `"GB"`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
geekTypes = ["GB", "GL", "GC", "GMC", "GCA", "GM", "GCM", "GMD", "GCS", "GMU", "GCC", "GPA", "GE", "GP", "GED", "GS", "GFA", "GSS", "GG", "GTW", "GH", "GO", "GIT", "GU", "GJ", "G!", "GLS", "GAT"]

loop do
  print "Type the code of your Geek type (ex : GB for Geek of Business) : "
  geekTypeUser = gets
  break if geekTypes.include?(geekTypeUser)
  puts "It is not a valid Geek Type !"
end

... continue to next step ...
```